# How to add a serialize a json to a class type and serialize that class without getting the \u0022

Tags: c#, .net

Trying to add a serialized string to another class string type, then that class needs to be serialized, but it's adding in the \u0022 because of the double serialization I realize. Is there way to make this work correctly so the \u0022 type representing the " is not added when Request class is serialized?

Fiddle code

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Request request= new Request();
            Contract contract = new Contract();
            contract.number= "12345";
            var contractSerialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(contract);
            Console.WriteLine(contractSerialized);

            request.dataObject= contractSerialized;
            var payload= JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);
            Console.WriteLine( payload );
        }
    }

    public class Request
    {
        public string dataObject { get; set; }
    }

    public class Contract
    {
        public string number { get; set; }
    }
```

Current output

```
   {"number":"12345"}
   {"dataObject":"{\u0022number\u0022:\u002212345\u0022}"}
```

Required output

```
   {"number":"12345"}
   {"dataObject":"{\"number\":\"12345\"}"}
```

Comment: Try using Newtonsoft.Json instead of JsonSerializer

Comment: Yep, that was it {"dataObject":"{\"number\":\"12345\"}"}. Thanks so much!

Comment: Why do you require that output? Both should end up being handled the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these characters are the ascii and you need to decode or skip these patterns from your response. Use the below code to decode the character

```
static string DecodeEncodedNonAsciiCharacters(string value)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(
                value,
                @"\\u(?<Value>[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})",
                m =>
                {
                    return ((char)int.Parse(m.Groups["Value"].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString();
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a different encoder, if changing library is not an option then use `UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping`:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
     Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping,
};
var payload= JsonSerializer.Serialize(request, options);
```

Beware that this method won't escape HTML and some other special characters so consider it to avoid potential XSS vulnerabilities.